# AWS SQS Event Source Mapping

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I want to process messages from sqs with the help of event source mapping.
I want my lambda function to make a batch of 10 messages, process them wait for atleast 10 seconds, and then proceed with the other messages in the queue. Repeat this until my queue is empty.

I tried to implement, but the problem I am facing is, when there are more messages in the queue the lambda is scaling.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your lambda to not scale you can use the maximum concurrency setting. Here is an AWS blog post that explains it: [Introducing maximum concurrency of AWS Lambda functions when using Amazon SQS as an event source | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-maximum-concurrency-of-aws-lambda-functions-when-using-amazon-sqs-as-an-event-source/)

If you use the aws cli to create your mapping, you can add the `ScalingConfig`parameter with the value you want:

```
aws lambda create-event-source-mapping \
--function-name my-function \
--ScalingConfig {MaxConcurrency=2} \
--event-source-arn arn:aws:sqs:us-east-2:123456789012:my-queue
```

If you really want to limit the lambda function to go above 2 concurrency, you can set the reserved concurrency to 1. See: [Configuring reserved concurrency - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html)

Comment: Thanks. 
But, I want this MaxConcurrency to be set as 1. But as per the docs(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_ScalingConfig.html) it cannot be set as 1

Comment: Ah, you didn't mention about not scaling above 1. then you can also use this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html